# XSD 1.1 Check if an attribute exists in another element

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I have 2 main sections in my XML file Sequence and StateRelations. The Sequence section is defined as. The Transition element should be unqiue based on its 4 properties as defined below.

```
<xs:element name="Transition">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Element1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="Element2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="Element3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="stateName" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="A" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="B" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="C" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Sequence">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Transition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xml:base"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniqueTransition">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//Transition"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@stateName"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@A"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@B"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@C"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

and StateRelations section is defined as follows. "*stateName1*" is actually a foreign key (keyref) which related to the "*stateName*" (key) of Transition. *Note: Relation element is actually recursive.*

```
<xs:element name="Relation">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Relation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="stateName1" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="StateRelations">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Relation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xml:base"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The problem comes in the following scenario. Since Transition has a unique constraint based on 4 attributes so the following XML is valid.

```
<Transition stateName="S3" A="a1" B="b1" C="c"/>
<Transition stateName="S3" A="a" B="b" C="c"/>
```

As you can see that *stateName=S3* can repeat multiple times. But this repetition breaks the primary-foreign key relationship between Transition and Relations. Reason: stateName can repeat in Transitions. Now, we have a conflict here. My end goal would be to have

1. Unique Sequences based on 4 attributes
2. and each *stateName1* in StateRelations should be a valid *stateName*
   defined in Transitions.

Till now, I know that key-keyref won't work in my scenario so I started looking into *assert* but I cannot get it to work. I have tried the following but nothing seems to be working.

```
    <xs:element name="Relation">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Relation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="stateName1" type="xs:string" use="required"/>

        <xs:assert test="matches( .//Transition/@stateName , @stateName1 )"/>
        <xs:assert test="/Replay/Sequence/Transition[contains(@stateName, @stateName1)]" />
        <xs:assert test="/Replay/Sequence/Transition[contains(@stateName, string( @stateName1 ))]/@stateName = string(@stateName1) "/>

    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**EDIT**: Here is the XSD (I have omitted some details).
Now, I want to somehow verify that `/Replay/StateRelations/Relation/@stateName1` exists in `/Replay/Sequence/Transition/@stateName`. I cannot use key/keyref because `/Replay/Sequence/Transition/@stateName` will not be unique.

```
<Replay>
   <xs:element name="Relation">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Relation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="stateName1" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:assert test="matches( .//Transition/@stateName , @stateName1 )"/>
        <xs:assert test="/Replay/Sequence/Transition[contains(@stateName, @stateName1)]" />
        <xs:assert test="/Replay/Sequence/Transition[contains(@stateName, string( @stateName1 ))]/@stateName = string(@stateName1) "/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="StateRelations">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Relation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xml:base"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Transition">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Element1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="Element2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="Element3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="stateName" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="A" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="B" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="C" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Sequence">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Transition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="xml:base"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniqueTransition">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//Transition"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@stateName"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@A"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@B"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@C"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
</Replay>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble working out the top-level structure of your document. Guessing from the paths in your non-working assertions, I guess your top-level element is Replay, and this has one branch `/Replay/Sequence/Transition` and perhaps another separate branch `/Replay/StateRelations/Relation`?

If that's the case, then the constraint that defines the relationship between `Transition` and `Relation` needs to be defined at the level of the common ancestor, which is `Replay`. You could define it using either key/keyref at this level, or using assertions, but either way constraints affecting two different elements always need to be defined at the level of the common ancestor: because it's the tree rooted at this ancestor that's the smallest self-contained part of the document that is invalid.

More specifically, note that assertions can't look at data outside the subtree rooted at the element on which the assertion is defined. It's an assertion about that element and its content, not an assertion about the surrounding context of that element.

Comment: Yes, my top level element is Replay. You are totally right. Thanks. Once, I moved my assertion to Replay level it worked fine. The only problem is that I cannot use key/keyref because stateName in transitions are not unique. So, since assertion is my only option and I have to define it outside the Relation tag, do I have use some sort of for loop in XPath to check if the stateNames defined in Relation exist in Transition ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand your structure well enough to understand why using key/keyRef is a problem. When you talk of loops in XPath, is this for key/keyRef or for assertions? XPath of course doesn't have loops, it is completely declarative and works on sets of nodes.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have updated my question.